# Pass user from passport to socket.io

Tags: express, socket.io, passport.js, connect-mongo

I am using passportjs, express 4, socket.io and to connect passportjs with socket i have added the passport.socketio with `connect-mongo` as Session Store. I saw in many posts that i have to avoid cors use. So when i use in client side code: `io.connect('/');`, none of functions is called(success/fail). When i use `io.connect('http://localhost:8565');`, fail function get called with Message: "No session found".
Store:

```
var store = new (require("connect-mongo")(session))({url: "mongodb://localhost/databaseName"});
```

Session:

```
var sessionMiddleware = session({
  key: 'your.sid-key',
  secret: 'reallyawesomesecret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: (365 * 24 * 60 * 60) },
  rolling: true,
  store: store
});
```

Passport.socketio:

```
io.use(passportSocketIo.authorize({
  cookieParser: cookieParser,
  key: 'your.sid-key',
  secret: 'reallyawesomesecret',
  store: store,
  success: onAuthorizeSuccess,
  fail: onAuthorizeFail
}));
```

Do i have to do something with the "key:'your.sid-key'," ? or i miss something else?
Inside function failed error get value `false` and `data.isAuthenticated()` is `true`, but `data.user` have `{logged_in: false}`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passport.socketio has issues finding session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456656/passport-socketio-has-issues-finding-session)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was in different place, on the client side code, i setup the socket with url localhost:port, when i change it to 127.0.0.1:port it worked out.