# Unable to access cookie value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

After clearing my browser history when I go to this URL: http://indianvisa-bangladesh.nic.in/visa/index.html

then I click on "Get Appointment" green link which takes us to http://indianvisa-bangladesh.nic.in/visa/Appointment_Login.jsp

Here it sets a `JSESSIONID` cookie. I can see this cookie in both Firefox/Chrome developer tools but can't access it using `document.cookie` in console.

When I type `document.cookie;` it shows empty string.

How do I print it?

**Edit:** Also this JSESSIONID cookie has `Path` value of "/visa"

[image]

Comment: I am getting cookie if I write document.cookie in console

Comment: @ParagBhayani very strange but I'm not able to access it.

Comment: it is access , may your chrome issue , update your chrome browser or check on an other browser if you have

Comment: same thing happening with Firefox too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason behind you can't read this cookie is because it is [HTTPOnly Cookie](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly), So if you are developer then you can set it easily false in your code when you are creating it. otherwise you can't get it using javascript. This is specifcally a feature rather than a bug provided by all major browsers.

See below for HTTP flag
[image]

More references:
[SOQuestion1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914744/javascript-document-cookie-always-empty-string),
[SOQuestion2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064318/how-to-read-a-secure-cookie-using-javascript),
[SOQuestion3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508027/cant-access-cookies-from-document-cookie-in-js-but-browser-shows-cookies-exist)