# Create cookie in C# and change the value via Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, cookies

Is it possible to access a C# created cookie via Javascript and change the value? (I'm aware that it's a security measure - but whats the alternative)

**C#**

```
 HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("theName", "theValue");
 Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

**Javascript**

```
console.log(document.cookie) //doesn't include my cookie..
```

Comment: if its HTTP cookie then you cant access them in javascript. Yes you can access the cookie and change the value in javascript.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to create a cookie, using c#, without restricting javascript access?

Comment: Where and when are you adding the cooking in C#?  Page_Load?

Comment: @jtimperley Global.asax

Comment: A cookie is a cookie, it is the same to create it from your C# code or from Javascript :)
So of course you can access it wherever you want (C# or JS)

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Many apologies,

Comment: Check to see how you are creating the cookie?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064318/how-to-read-a-secure-cookie-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

HttpCookie is by default protected - i.e. Javascript cannot read them. Setting the following bool property allows access.

```
myCookie.HttpOnly = false
```