# expressjs, nginx proxy, csurf and secure cookies not working

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, express-session

I've got an Express site running behind a proxy with nginx, everything was working fine on my local development machine with regards to csrf protection using csurf and insecure cookies.

I've since moved to a staging site which has an SSL cert. Now I'm using SSL I want to enable secure cookies. However csurf now always errors with an invalid csrf token whenever I submit a form.

I setup my express-session like so:

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1)
app.use(session({secret:'secret' , resave:false,proxy:true, saveUninitialized:false, store:sessionStore, rolling:true, cookie:{secure:true}}))
//...other setup lines
let csrf = csurf()
app.use(csrf)
```

and my nginx set-up is as follows:

```
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header x-forwarded-proto https;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
```

As far as I can tell from the docs this should all be fine. My webapp is running from GCP, but I don't think that should make any difference.

I've tried clearing my cookies etc. on my machine in case something was cached somewhere but it still won't work. Moving back to `secure:false` fixes the issue.

I have a catch all `app.post` route handler to validate a csrf token as there are multiple forms on the page and the new csrf token is created after this route has fired and as I mentioned earlier this all worked fine without secure cookies as well. I've also tried passing my session secret to the `cookieParser()` as well but to no avail and the solutions at [Express-session Secure Cookies not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44039069/express-session-secure-cookies-not-working) also don't work (such as setting `resave:true`). There's no AJAX requests going on either it's a straight `POST` and the token is rendered correctly in the form.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did something similar, and at least on my setup I had to specify the following array in my `trust proxy` in express.

```
app.set('trust proxy', ['loopback', 'linklocal', 'uniquelocal']);
```

I also believe express wants to see all of the standard `x-forwarded` headers, not just `-proto`. Here's the config I used for them:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct, but it looks like my problem was more stupidity, I forgot to restart nginx after the config change even though I'd restarted my node app. Doh!

Comment: Thanks. Setting the proxy headers in nginx fixed it for me!