# NodeJS Express Session isn't being restored between routes in kubernetes

Tags: node.js, express, session, auth0

We have a NodeJS `express` server with `express-session` and `express-mysql-session` enabled. We've connected the session database and can verify there are sessions being created. Our app redirects users without a token cookie to Auth0 for authentication, and they are redirected back to our app at `/callback`. It does successfully set our ID token that allows our user to be logged in. However, the passport auth0 strategy complains that it cannot verify the authentication state.

```
'Unable to verify authorization request state.'
```

The server code is below, with some other parts commented out. Connecting to the session database is successful since we can see our sessions get created with each request.

```
const options = {
  database: process.env.SESSION_DB_NAME || "sessions",
  host: process.env.SESSION_DB_HOST! as string,
  password: process.env.SESSION_DB_PASSWORD! as string,
  port: parseInt(process.env.SESSION_DB_PASSWORD || "3306", 10),
  user: process.env.SESSION_DB_USER! as string,
};
const sessionStore = new MySQLStore(options);

app.use(
  session({
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // 1 day
      secure: true,
    },
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET!,
    store: sessionStore,
  })
);

app.get("/login", (request, response, next) => {
  // if there is no session, it's a server error
  if (!request.session) {
    console.error(new Error("No session in /login"));
    return response.status(500).send("Server error: No Session");
  }

  return passport.authenticate("auth0", {
    scope: "openid email profile",
  })(request, response, next);
});

console.log("router: Auth0 Callback");
app.get("/callback", (request, response, next) => {
  const domain = request.hostname;
  console.log(request.session);

  passport.authenticate("auth0", (auth0Error, token, info) => {
    // if there was a problem authenticating
    if (auth0Error) {
      console.error(auth0Error);
      return response.status(500).send();
    }

    // ensure we have a session. The middleware should be giving us one.
    if (!request.session) {
      console.error("No session in /callback.");
      return response.status(500).send();
    }

    // if we couldn't log in
    if (!token) {
      if (info) {
        console.log(info);
        return response.status(500).send(info.message);
      }

      // redirect to the login page
      return response.status(401).send("Cannot log you in.");
    }

    // parse the token we get
    const user = jwt.decode(token);

    // if there is no valid user token, we've got bigger problems
    if (!user) {
      console.error("Token is falsey after authenticating.");
      return response.status(500).send();
    } else if (typeof user === "string") {
      console.error("Cannot decode JWT after authenticating");
      return response.status(500).send();
    }

    request.logIn(user, (logInError) => {
      // redirect to desired route
      // ...
    });
  })(request, response, next);
});

router.get("/*", (request, response, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("jwt", (authenticationError, isAuthenticated, info) => {
    // Log in successful via existing JWT
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      return next();
    }

    // handle unauthenticated situations
    // ...
  })(request, response, next);
});
```

I've tried the following suggestions at https://github.com/auth0/passport-auth0/issues/70:

- app.set("trust proxy", 1")
- session cookie already set to secure
- serving only on https
- using mysql session store and default in-memory store

We are running the server in a kubernetes cluster using ClusterIP for our ingress. Env variables are being set correctly, I'm pretty sure. When I run this locally I do not have any issues.

What could cause the session to not be restored but instead recreated with each request?

Comment: How did you fix the problem? I'm running into the same issue. I'm running nodejs on heroku

Comment: @ChrisHansen I'm not sure whether we ever did resolve it. Looking back through our commits, I think it was more of a mitigation. If we caught that exception log, we tried another login attempt automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was posted over a year ago so I figure you've already fixed it, but I thought I'd post my solution to help others. I very recently ran into the same issue, although I was using an Apache reverse proxy instead of a Kubernetes cluster.

I've posted my solution in another SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67891167/8221175

In short, my Apache configuration was missing these lines:

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-SSL expr=%{HTTPS}

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8001/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8001/
```

This, along with other session/cookie configuration for express (see the SO link) fixed it. My sessions now persist and I no longer have the issue.

For those interested in why the 'Unable to verify authorization request state.' message is issued, check out my answer in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/auth0/passport-auth0/issues/89#issuecomment-856971807

Comment: I'm running into the same issue on heroku with a nodejs setup. Can you answer my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71145818/unable-to-verify-authorization-state-on-heroku?