# Get cookie name and values using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, browser, session-cookies

On a web page, I need all the cookies' name and value. The problem is that,
for example, on Google Chrome, I can see cookie information using 
**Developers Tools > Resources > Cookies**, but it returns an empty string when I type "document.cookie" on the console.

Is there a 'javascript way' to display the coookie information as it is seen in the Resources tab?

Comment: There are HTTP only cookies that cannot be accessed via JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064318/how-to-read-a-secure-cookie-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those cookies are HTTP-only cookies and you cannot access them via Javascript. This would cause major security vulnerabilities.

For more clarification on security check OWASP documentation

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly