# Protecting web application from CSRF attack using Spring Security

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-security, csrf

I am implementing CSRF protection in my web application.

I have used `org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository` class to generate the X-XSRF token. This token is being sent as cookie in every request's response.

UI component which is a single page application deployed on different server is read this cookie and read the X-XSRF token from cookie and set it as header in all subsequent requests.

Spring validates the received X-XSRF token and allow/deny the request. This works fine.

But their is a constraint this X-XSRF cookie has to be `httpOnly` is `false` so that client side JavaScript can read it.

We cannot read a cookie for which `httpOnly` is `true`.

Is there any other alternative to protect web application CSRF in an web application where X-XSRF token cookie `httpOnly` is `true`.

Using JavaScript method (`document.cookie`) I can not read the cookies for which `httpOnly` attribute is set to `true`, see:

- [How to read a secure cookie using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064318/how-to-read-a-secure-cookie-using-javascript)
- [Secure and HttpOnly cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Secure_and_HttpOnly_cookies)
- [Cross-Site Request Forgery Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md)

I can not made the changes to make all the cookies as `httpOnly` is `false` in Websphere.

Or am I missing something where client side JavaScript can read the cookie which is `httpOnly` is `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-cookie):

> **CookieCsrfTokenRepository**
>
> There can be cases where users will want to persist the `CsrfToken` in a cookie. By default the `CookieCsrfTokenRepository` will write to a cookie named `XSRF-TOKEN` and read it from a header named `X-XSRF-TOKEN` or the HTTP parameter `_csrf`. These defaults come from AngularJS
>
> You can configure `CookieCsrfTokenRepository` in XML using the following:
>
> ```xml
> <http>
>     <!-- ... -->
>     <csrf token-repository-ref="tokenRepository"/>
> </http>
> <b:bean id="tokenRepository"
>     class="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository"
>     p:cookieHttpOnly="false"/>
> ```
>
> The sample explicitly sets `cookieHttpOnly=false`. This is necessary to allow JavaScript (i.e. AngularJS) to read it. If you do not need the ability to read the cookie with JavaScript directly, it is recommended to omit `cookieHttpOnly=false` to improve security.
>
> You can configure `CookieCsrfTokenRepository` in Java Configuration using:
>
> ```java
> @EnableWebSecurity
> public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>
>     @Override
>     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>         http
>             .csrf()
>                 .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The sample explicitly sets `cookieHttpOnly=false`. This is necessary to allow JavaScript (i.e. AngularJS) to read it. If you do not need the ability to read the cookie with JavaScript directly, it is recommended to omit `cookieHttpOnly=false` (by using new `CookieCsrfTokenRepository()` instead) to improve security.

Comment: I agree !! so it looks like if client java script wants to read this XSRF-TOKEN from cookie and send it back to server as part of header X-XSRF-TOKEN for all the subsequent requests in order to validate the request is true and valid, the XSRF-TOKEN cookie httpOnly property has to be false.