# FastAPI is not returning cookies to React frontend

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, axios, fastapi

Why doesn't FastAPI return the cookie to my frontend, which is a React app?

Here is my code:

```
@router.post("/login")
def user_login(response: Response,username :str = Form(),password :str = Form(),db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.mobile_number==username).first()
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(400, detail='wrong phone number or password')
    if not verify_password(password, user.password):
        raise HTTPException(400, detail='wrong phone number or password')
    
   
    access_token = create_access_token(data={"sub": user.mobile_number})
    response.set_cookie(key="fakesession", value="fake-cookie-session-value") #here I am set cookie 
    return {"status":"success"}
```

When I login from Swagger UI autodocs, I can see the cookie in the response headers using DevTools on Chrome browser. However, when I login from my React app, no cookie is returned. I am using axios to send the request like this:

`await axios.post(login_url, formdata)`

Comment: What is the actual response? Is it 200 OK, or is there an error that occurs? What does the response headers look like?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, create the cookie, as shown in the example below, and make sure there is no error returned when performing the Axios POST request, and that you get a `'status': 'success'` response with `200` status code. You may want to have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74060795/17865804) as well, which provides explains how to use the `max_age` and `expires` flags too.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
def main(response: Response):
    response.set_cookie(key='token', value='some-token-value', httponly=True) 
    return {'status': 'success'}
```

Second, as you mentioned that you are using React in the frontend—which needs to be listening on a different port from the one used for the FastAPI backend, meaning that you are performing [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) requests—you need to set the [`withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) property to `true` (by default this is set to `false`), in order to allow receiving/sending credentials, such as [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) and [HTTP authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication) headers, from/to other origins. Two servers with same domain and protocol, but **different** ports, e.g., `http://localhost:8000` and `http://localhost:3000` are considered different origins (see [FastAPI documentation on CORS](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804), which provides details around cookies in general, as well as solutions for setting cross-domain cookies—which you don't actually need in your case, as the domain is the same for both the backend and the frontend, and hence, setting the cookie as usual would work just fine).

**Note** that if you are accessing your React frontend by typing `http://localhost:3000` in the address bar of your browser, then your Axios requests to FastAPI backend **should** use the `localhost` domain in the URL, e.g., `axios.post('http://localhost:8000',...`, and **not** `axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000',...`, as `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are two **different domains**, and hence, the cookie would otherwise fail to be created for the `localhost` domain, as it would be created for `127.0.0.1`, i.e., the domain used in the `axios` request (and then, that would be a case for cross-domain cookies, as described in the linked answer above, which again, in your case, would not be needed).

Thus, to accept cookies sent by the server, you need to use `withCredentials: true` in your Axios request; otherwise, the cookies will be ignored in the response (which is the default behaviour, when `withCredentials` is set to `false`; hence, preventing different domains from setting cookies for their own domain). The same `withCredentials: true` property has to be included in  every subsequent request to your API, if you would like the cookie to be sent to the server, so that the user can be authenticated and provided access to protected routes.

Hence, an Axios request that includes credentials should look like this:

```js
await axios.post(url, data, {withCredentials: true}))
```

The equivalent in a `fetch()` request (i.e., using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)) is [`credentials: 'include'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included). The default value for `credentials` is `same-origin`. Using `credentials: 'include'` will cause the browser to include credentials in both same-origin and cross-origin requests, as well as set any cookies sent back in cross-origin responses. For instance:

```js
fetch('https://example.com', {
  credentials: 'include'
});
```

### Important Note

Since you are performing a cross-origin request, for either the above to work, you would need to **explicitly specify** the allowed origins, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805329/17865804) (behind the scenes, that is setting the [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) response header). For instance:

```py
origins = ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
           'https://localhost:3000', 'https://127.0.0.1:3000']
```

Using [the `*` wildcard](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/#wildcards) instead would mean that **all** origins are allowed; however, that would also only allow certain types of communication, **excluding** everything that involves `credentials`, such as **cookies**, **authorization** headers, etc—hence, you should not use the `*` wildcard.

Also, make sure to set `allow_credentials=True` when using the [`CORSMiddleware`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/#use-corsmiddleware) (which sets the [`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials) response header to `true`).

Example (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805329/17865804)):

```py
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

Comment: Also make sure to set your Cookie's `SameSite` to `none` (`lax` did not work for me), see this answer for more https://stackoverflow.com/a/72024519/9878135

Comment: @Myzel394 Please **DON'T** set the [`SameSite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) flag to `None`, as the cookie would **not be protected** from external access (use with [`cross-domain cookies`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804) **only**).

Comment: @Myzel394  If you are creating cookies for the same domain (e.g., `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1`), setting that flag to `Lax` or `Strict` should be fine. Note that `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are considered to be different domains (the same applies to `https://localhost` and `http://localhost` - note the **s** in the first domain, which uses the `HTTPS` protocol); hence, if you are accessing your frontend at  `http://localhost`, make sure that your axios request uses `http://localhost`, not `http://127.0.0.1`, and vice versa.

Comment: for development it's fine to set your cookies to `None`, for production however, you are totally right to not set it to `None`.

Comment: @Myzel394 I am afraid that's not how it works. I would suggest you have a look at the answer above (including the references), as well as the comments above to better understand how things work, and that in the above case (where **same-domain** cookies need to be created), you **don't** have to and **shouldn't** set the `SameSite` flag to `None`. Making that mistake during development, it would be easier for you to make it in production as well. Read more about cross-site and same-site cookies [here](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/01/get-ready-for-new-samesitenone-secure).