# CORS error with Nextjs application using API gateway, only on client side

Tags: javascript, next.js, axios, cors, fastapi

I'm not sure how to describe the problem to its fullest, I'm already a week in playing with this and can't get it to work...

I have a FastAPI server running as Lambda connected to API Gateway

[image]

CORS is enabled in both FastAPI and API Gateway.

I have NextJS running on Amplify, the requests that NextJS is performing are working, but the requests on my client side do not and have a CORS error.

my API is `api.example.com/api` while App is `example.com`

**What Iv'e tried:**

- Adding the following headers to each request  `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*', "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'`
- Adding re-writes to make sort of a proxy
- Using CORS chrome extension, still does not work

**Signup route which is done by next and not the client works**

[image]

**yet request done by client**

[image]

I've prob tried many more things in between, I'm just clueless

This is my code for creating Axios Instance (Removed the headers but it did not work with them also)

```
import axios from 'axios';


export const api = (session: any): any => {
    const headers: { [key: string]: string | number } = {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
    }

    if (session?.user) {
        headers.Authorization = session.user.token;
    }

    const api = axios.create({
        baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_DOMAIN,
        withCredentials: true,
        headers
    });


    return api;
};
```

Any help is very very much appreciated

***EDIT:***

**ERROR itself**

[image]

The lambda does not seems to even get the requests that done by my client, only the ones from Nextjs backend.

It makes me think it's the API Gateway configuration or my client request headers configuration.

Also tried:

- Adding `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header as true, on client, and API gateway.
- Added for my FastAPI CORS middleware-specific **set of origins** with my `https://example.com`

Comment: Also tried to delete cache, remove cache in dev tools etc...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FastAPI is not returning cookies to React frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73962743/fastapi-is-not-returning-cookies-to-react-frontend)

Comment: No, I tried to set up credentials as true and allow specific origins, both in the API gateway and in my FastAPI code..

Comment: @Chris I've added more information :D thanks!

Comment: Before a POST a browser wil do an OPTION request (preflight request). Check if the CORS headers are included for OPTION requests with a tool like postman

Comment: None of this is related to the client-side (and you definitely should not add any `Access-Control-*` headers to your requests). The error is literally telling you what the problem is; the response to the preflight request does not have `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`

Comment: @Phil I do have it set up in API gateway, is there a special setup also in FastAPI that should be done? in the FastAPI console I don't see any response to the preflight request hence I think it get stopped in API gateway, and there in the settings I enabled CORS with credetials: true for my {proxy+} resource

Comment: @n9iels can you point out what exact headers to verify, I do see CORS headers given in the response.

Comment: methods to debug: try making the same request by postman via copying curl and importing it in postman see if you are able to make that request, if yes then please share your cors policy at server like allowed headers, origin, methods, credentials. check if you have option method added to your allowed methods.

Comment: @DanishHasan here are the headers - https://prnt.sc/Ct5-N5Oojf1- 
it seems the API Gateway does return the CORS

Comment: Also seem like options should return the Credentials header as configured in API Gateway https://prnt.sc/N9JsadV3O0UA  I'm confused why it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, for anyone experiencing CORS issues with API Gateway and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header, my Integration Request was of `type Mock`, so my configuration did not apply.

I was with an AWS expert (paid service) 40 min call and we missed it lmao, feels bad.