# Cookie not being set after a Google Auth2 callback

Tags: cookies, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, fastapi, session-cookies

I'm using FastAPI and making a google authentication call.
However the cookie is not being set after it comes back from the authentication.
I've tried skipping the authentication and going straight to the callback and the cookie setting works. But it's when I do the Google authentication first, it doesn't then seem to set the cookie despite it reaching that part of the code and finishing as without errors.

```
@router.get("/login", tags=['Google SSO'])
async def google_login():
    with GoogleSSO(
        GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        "http://localhost:8000/v1/google/callback",
        allow_insecure_http=True
    ) as google_sso:
        return await google_sso.get_login_redirect(params={"prompt": "consent", "access_type": "offline"})


@router.get("/callback", tags=['Google SSO'])
async def google_callback(request: Request, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
        access_token = 'test'
        response = RedirectResponse(url="http://127.0.0.1:3000/home", status_code=status.HTTP_302_FOUND)
        response.set_cookie(
            key=SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
            value=access_token,
            httponly=True,
            domain="127.0.0.1",  # Set the domain to match your front end URL
            path="/",  # Set the path to '/' to make the cookie available across the entire site
        )
        return response
```

Comment: You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804) helpful

Answer (score 0):

Ok I made some headway on this. If you are having similar issues where you have
already tried setting all this:

```
httponly=True,
            domain="127.0.0.1",  # Set the domain to match your front end URL
            path="/",
```

Then refer to the top bit of the code where I am using:

```
http://localhost:8000/v1/google/callback"
```

My actual testing being done on 127.0.0.1 not localhost, so I had to change it to: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/google/callback",
and I had to change the allowed callback URI to this in Google console.

This now leaves me with the issue that it works first time, but when the user has been logged in once and I try it again it fails.
Will see if I can figure that bit out.