# Can we delete HttpOnly and Secured Cookies using javascript ,jsp or java or html?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, cookies

Can we delete **HttpOnly** and **Secured** Cookies using javascript ,jsp or java or html?

Is it possible to write some code and clear out all the cookies from browser? Does not matter if it is a secured or an HttpOnly, I want to delete it anyway. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. A cookie with the `HttpOnly` attribute is inaccessible to JavaScript. `HttpOnly` cookie helps to mitigate cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.
Refer: [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#:%7E:text=A%20cookie%20with%20the%20HttpOnly,cross-site%20scripting%20(XSS)%20attacks.)

[How to read a HttpOnly cookie using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064318/how-to-read-a-httponly-cookie-using-javascript)

To clear all the cookies (without httpOnly attribute) from the browser refer: [Clearing all cookies with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript)