# node js does not send cookies to react client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I haven't been able to solve this problem for 2 days, node js api heroku is also deployed, my client is on netlify, the backend does not send cookies when requesting from the client, you set the corss, I added withCredintels, but in vain, what can I do, (I allowed google cookies)

client expample fetch

```
const response = await axios(`${client}api/csrf`, {
    method: "GET",
    withCredentials: true,
    header: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
      mode: "same-origin",
      redirect: "follow",
    },
  });
  axios.defaults.headers.common["X-CSRF-Token"] = response.data.csrf;
```

server.js

```
app.set("trust proxy", true);
app.use(limiter);

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.frameguard({ action: "deny" }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/backend/build"));
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "https://atalay.netlify.app",
    credentials: true,
    methods: "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE",
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    allowedHeaders: [
      "Origin",
      "X-Requested-With",
      "Content-Type",
      "Accept",
      "Authorization",
    ],
    preflightContinue: true,
  })
);

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin);
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  next();
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Set-Cookie", "HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=None");
  next();
});

app.use(
  session({
    secret: config.sessionSecret,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
      httpOnly: false,
    },
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: true,
    },
    store: MongoDBStore({
      uri: "procsess.env.DB",
      collection: "sessions",
    }),
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(csrf({ cookie: false }));


app.use("/api", router);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a HttpOnly cookie using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064318/how-to-read-a-httponly-cookie-using-javascript) HTTPOnly cookies cannot be accesses through JavaScript

Comment: no , not working

Comment: I set cors, I added withCredintals to axios requests, same problem