# using HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Set()

Tags: asp.net, cookies, httpcontext

I've seen this in some code and I'm a little confused about when you would use that method.  Sure, the `Get()` method makes sense for a request, but wouldn't you ordinarily use a `Set()` method for cookies in the `Response.Cookies` object, rather than `Request.Cookies`?

Comment: Did you have a look at that thread :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573922/when-to-use-request-cookies-over-response-cookies

Comment: Yes I did.  It does a fine job explaining that typically you set response cookies and get request cookies.  But when (under what circumstances) would you set a request cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have some code that expects a cookie in the request, but under some circumstances this cookie is not present. In this case you could set the cookie in the request to a default value.

Also, if you are testing code that relies on cookies being present in the request (when doing [unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) for example), then of course you need a way to set cookies without a browser (unit testing calls for testing code in isolation).