# ASP.NET Request.Cookies.Get("Cookie") Returns Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

The question seems to have been asked many times, but I can't find an answer that helped me.

I have code in the code-behind of a master page file which sets a cookie when a dropdown control is changed.  If I comment out the redirect line I can see that the cookie is properly set, because creating a new cookie and outputting its value successfully displays the new value of the changed dropdown.

If I allow the redirect to take place, however, the code in the page_load will report that the cookie set is null.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
protected void ThemeSelection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    HttpCookie themeCookie = new HttpCookie("PreferredTheme");
    themeCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3);
    themeCookie.Value = ThemeSelection.SelectedValue;

    Request.Cookies.Add(themeCookie);

    HttpCookie cookieCheck = Request.Cookies.Get("PreferredTheme");
    Response.Write(cookieCheck.Value);

    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());

}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    HttpCookie preferredTheme = Request.Cookies.Get("PreferredTheme");

    if (preferredTheme == null)
    {
        Response.Write("PreferredTheme is null");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the cookie to survive between requests, you need to use **Response**.Cookies....to send the cookie to the client.   When the next Request comes in, the cookie will be there.

[When to use Request.Cookies over Response.Cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573922/when-to-use-request-cookies-over-response-cookies)

Comment: Came here to fix my question because I realized my stupid error and saw that you had responded.  Thanks!